# Finding all variables created by assignment - Not working for pairlist

Tags: r, expression, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm currently doing [Advanced-R, 18 Expressions](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/expressions.html#expression-special).

Topic is about 18.5.2 Finding all variables created by assignment, but the given code doesn't work in the case of pairlist.

I followed all the given codes, but the results are not quite same with what I expect.

To begin with, in order to figure out what the type of the input, `expr_type()` is needed.

```r
expr_type <- function(x) {
    if(rlang::is_syntactic_literal(x)) {
        "constant"
    } else if (is.symbol(x)) {
        "symbol"
    } else if (is.call(x)) {
        "call"
    } else if (is.pairlist(x)) {
        "pairlist"
    } else {
        typeof(x)
    }
}
```

And the author, hadley, coupled this with a wrapper around the switch function.

```r
switch_expr <- function(x, ...) {
  switch(expr_type(x),
    ...,
    stop("Don't know how to handle type ", typeof(x), call. = FALSE)
  )
}
```

In the case of base cases, symbol and constant, is trivial because neither represents assignment.

```r
find_assign_rec <- function(x) {
  switch_expr(x,
    constant = ,
    symbol = character()
  )
}
```

In the case of recursive cases, especially for pairlists, he suggested

```r
flat_map_chr <- function(.x, .f, ...) {
  purrr::flatten_chr(purrr::map(.x, .f, ...))
}
```

So summing up, it follows

```r
find_assign_rec <- function(x) {
  switch_expr(x,
    # Base cases
    constant = ,
    symbol = character(),

    # Recursive cases
    pairlist = flat_map_chr(as.list(x), find_assign_rec),
  )
}

find_assign <- function(x) find_assign_rec(enexpr(x))
```

Then, I expect in the case of `pl <- pairlist(x = 1, y = 2)`, `find_assign(pl)` should return `#> [1] "x" "y"`

But the actual output is `character(0)`

What is wrong with this?